# ACS Token replay detection feature

Tags: wif, acs

Does ACS has token replay detection feature similar to ADFS?

If the replay detection is implemented at Relying Party, still the IdP issued tokens can be replayed (since ACS accepts it and issues a new token to RP, if its within the validity period.

Answer (score 0):

ACS doesn't explicitly provide replay detection, though you may get it for free depending on the identity provider and protocol. This is why you should sign out and close your browser to ensure that sign-out is complete.